# Unable to use the web link from the second layout

Tags: java, android, layout, hyperlink

So I have a simple program that has an image and a button. When the button is clicked, an alert dialog box is opened with a web link.

My problem is getting the web link to work without crashing the app (giving a null object reference error).

I've looked through Layoutinflaters and Fragments, but can't seem to make the program do what I want.

```
package com.test.test;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView mShowDialog = findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);
    mShowDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_popup, null);

            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
            dialog.show();

            //link is null
            TextView link = findViewById(R.id.linkText);
            //Crashes the app before it starts
            link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    });
}
}
```

I believe the error stems from this code, but will provide the xml files on request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem by breaking this code into two activities. The main activity, and a fragment activity.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setupPopup();

}

private void setupPopup() {

    ImageView btn = findViewById(R.id.btnShowDialog);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            PopupFragment dialog = new PopupFragment();
            dialog.show(manager, "MessageDialog");
        }
    });

}

}
```

Fragment Activity:

```
public class PopupFragment extends AppCompatDialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
            .inflate(R.layout.info_popup, null);

    final TextView link = v.findViewById(R.id.linkText);
    link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            link.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        }
    });

    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(v)
            .create();
}
}
```

There might be better ways, but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

A better option would be to link in the XML. You do not appear to be setting it in code, so the above is all unnecessary. Here is an example.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/lnkHelpInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:linksClickable="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:text="https://www.google.com"/>
```

If you prefer to do this in code because you want the text to show something different, then using the linkmethod doesn't really provide you any value. Just make your text underline and blue. Then handle in code.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: That's what I had originally, but it did not let me create a link out of any text. Instead of clicking on "https://www.google.com", I would prefer to click on "Go to Google" as the link. For reasons.